# Invoke-Command error "Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters"

Tags: powershell

Hope you can help me with a problem trying to execute a script block with alternate credentials on a local computer. I've been thoroughly searching on forums and doing some googling and found two possible approach to solve my problem:

1. Use Invoke-Command
2. Use Start-Job

Using approach #1 I had this code:

```
$res = Invoke-Command -Credential $migratorCreds -ScriptBlock {param($one, $two) Get-LocalUsers -parentNodeXML $one -migratorUser $two } -ArgumentList $xmlPRE,$migratorCreds
```

where `Get-LocalUsers` is a custom function stored in a custom module (*.psm1).

My problem is that every time I run this code I get following error:

> Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

So it's obvious that I must be missing something, could you help me on this topic?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The error you have is because `-credential` without `-computername` can't exist.

You can try this way:

```
Invoke-Command -Credential $migratorCreds  -ScriptBlock ${function:Get-LocalUsers} -ArgumentList $xmlPRE,$migratorCreds -computername YOURCOMPUTERNAME
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked perfectly although I have another problem with WinRM, but I'll try solve it by myself before asking ;)

Comment: you can use localhost instead of YOURCOMPUTERNAME for reusability.

Comment: @rob I think no. `localhost` will resolve always the local computer name and not the remote one....

Comment: @CB that was the point, this error comes up when you try "invoke-command" on a local machine (where you are trying to execute the command with different credentials), i.e. not passing the -ComputerName parameter.

Comment: @rob oops... I commented without reading again the OP. Sorry ;)

Comment: how do you know which parameters are required?

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is correct regarding the Invoke-Command cmdlet, but more broadly speaking, cmdlets can have [parameter sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-parameter-sets) where groups of input parameters are defined, such that you can't use two parameters that aren't members of the same parameter set.

If you're running into this error with any other cmdlet, look up its Microsoft documentation, and see if the the top of the page has distinct sets of parameters listed. For example, the documentation for [Set-AzureDeployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/set-azuredeployment?view=azuresmps-4.0.0) defines three sets at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly new to using PowerShell, think I might be able to help.
Could you try this?

I believe you're not getting the correct parameters to your script block:

```
param([string]$one, [string]$two)
$res = Invoke-Command -Credential $migratorCreds -ScriptBlock {Get-LocalUsers -parentNodeXML $args[0] -migratorUser $args[1] } -ArgumentList $xmlPRE, $migratorCreds
```

Comment: Thanks @bootleboot for your reply, but actualy @C.B. approach solved my problem.It had to do with `-Computer` parameter. Anyway, thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

I was solving same problem recently. I was designing a write cmdlet for my [Subtitle](https://github.com/KUTlime/PowerShell-Subtitle-Module) module. I had six different user stories:

- Subtitle only
- Subtitle and path (original file name is used)
- Subtitle and new file name (original path is used)
- Subtitle and name suffix is used (original path and modified name is used).
- Subtile, new path and new file name is is used.
- Subtitle, new path and suffix is used.

I end up in the big frustration because I though that 4 parameters will be enough. Like most of the times, the frustration was pointless because it was my fault. I didn't know enough about parameter sets.

After some research in documentation, I realized where is the problem. With knowledge how the parameter sets should be used, I developed a general and simple approach how to solve this problem. A pencil and a sheet of paper is required but a spreadsheet editor is better:

1. Write down all intended ways how the cmdlet should be used => user stories.
2. Keep adding parameters with meaningful names and mark the use of the parameters until you have a unique collection set => no repetitive combination of parameters.
3. Implement parameter sets into your code.
4. Prepare tests for all possible user stories.
5. Run tests (big surprise, right?). IDEs doesn't checks parameter sets collision, tests could save lots of trouble later one.

Example:

[image: Unique parameter binding resolution approach.]

The practical example could be seen [over here](https://github.com/KUTlime/PowerShell-Subtitle-Module/blob/master/Subtitle/Subtitle.psm1).

BTW: The parameter uniqueness within parameter sets is the reason why the `ParameterSetName` property doesn't support `[String[]]`. It doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Hi, your answer might be a good and useful approach for the general problem, but as the question author commented in the second answer, he was not looking for a solution for the parameter set related error, but for invoking  a command with another user - although I think the question title is pretty misleading. If I understand your answer correctly, you are writing from a Module developer's perspective, not from a user's perspective. If no corresponding question exists you could just make a self-answer --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @BernhardStadler Not really. The perspective from a module developer and somebody who is just scripting does not really matter in this particular problem. This binding error is cause when somebody doesn't fully understand how parameter sets in PowerShell works. Nothing else.
This is only topic on SO which is addressing this issue and I've considered self-answer as unreasonable duplicate.