# Powershell: Can't run script as different user in same window?

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins, remote-access, credentials

I am running a script that involves writing to a database only certain users have access to, so we are running the script as a different user (passing in those user credentials) on our corporate network.

Despite trying things like `-NoNewWindow` or `-WindowStyle Hidden`, it always seems to pop up in a new window. This is an issue because when we launch the script from our Jenkins builder with a powershell build step, Jenkins doesn't like the second window and really appears to need it all in the main window.

We are using `Start-Process`, and the script call looks similar to this (I cut some of the details out):

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow powershell.exe -Credential $credential -ArgumentList “Start-Process powershell.exe 'path\script.ps1 -param1 xxx -param2 yyy' -Verb runAs”
```

Any ideas as to how to get this to actually run without a popup window?
Thanks!

Comment: Is it not possible to enter the commands of `path\script.ps1` in the job's config directly rather than spawning new processes? Why is `Start-Process powershell.exe` in your `-ArgumentList` again? Shouldn't just the script be started with the first `powershell.exe` process?

Comment: You can indeed run a script directly in the build config, but in order to pass in credentials like we need that is a parameter of Start-Process... I do not know why we need start process in the arguments either, it doesnt seem to run at all without it. I am just an intern and working with my manager for a bit on it yesterday that is what he came up with. He has used similar commands but it doesnt seem to work here.

Comment: is invoke-command not an option for you : `Invoke-Command -FilePath -Credential`

Comment: Invoke-Command -FilePath 'path\script.ps1 -param1 param -param2 param2' -Credential $credential        Is something formatted wrong here? I get a parameter binding error, the script takes in two parameters, also $credential is a variable for a PSCredential object

Comment: use the -argumentlist parameter, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command

Comment: How would we implement this with the argument list, I had that originally when I was using start process

Comment: `invoke-command -scriptblock { param($param1)} -ArgumentList "param1value"`  when using a scriptblock instead of a file

Comment: `Invoke-Command -Filepath "path\script.ps1" -credential $cred -argumentlist "param1","param2","param3"`

Answer (score 0):

one of these should do the trick to you

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'Same computer Name' -Credential '(PAss Cred object here)' -ScriptBlock {'Your Scripts Here'} 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'Same computer Name' -Credential '(PAss Cred object here)' -FilePath 'FilePAthHere'
```

Comment: Hmm neither worked... why is the computer name needed? I omitted that part since we arent trying to run on a remote computer, just as a different user

Comment: Thats fine,How Did u Pass the Credential?

Comment: Thats Because -credential without -computername can't exist

Comment: Ah so if we are running on the same computer and not remotely, what do we do for computer name

Comment: @Paul https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144016/powershell-parameter-set-cannot-be-resolved-using-the-specified-named-parameter  Somedays ago I had discovered it,Luckily I have the link to it too .(The First Solution in the link)

Comment: Cheers :) @Paul

Comment: When running this in jenkins: Invoke-Command -ComputerName PLS-MRE-BUILD02 -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {E:\Jenkins\workspace\$branch\Automation\Source\ART\ARTController.ps1 -environment $environment -branch $branch}  We get the error saying E:\jenkins... isnt recognized as a cmdlet or function...

Comment: See here ,you are using a script block,Meaning you need to put Complete code in it.

Comment: This may be a dumb question but what do you mean by complete code? Is it not the script/parameters like regular powershell code?

Comment: @JustinM. -scriptblock{ should contain of the contents of ArtController.ps1}

Comment: @JustinM please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command ... Understand what's happening behind the wheels,,, that will help you do better